# In Objective-C how do you entirely replace a method of a parent class, while preserving that parent method's inherited functionality?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Basically I have a class hierarchy something like this:

```
NSObject
  MySpecialController
    MyExtraSpecialController
```

Each of these has an `init` method, and each implementation calls `super` first to let the superclass initialize itself first, all the way up the chain. For lack of better terminology I would say that each class "augments" its super class' behaviour.

But let's suppose I want to "replace" my super class's behaviour entirely (simply because I want to specialize it further for a particular app, but without cluttering the generic reusable super class. So it is assumed that I have intimate knowledge of the super class). The actual change that I want to do is replace a property with one of a more specific class type. To fully implement this I need the `init` method to instantiate an instance of `widget` of the appropriate class. So if I instantiate a `MySpecialController`, its `widget` property should be of type `MySpecialWidget`; but if I instantiate a `MyExtraSpecialController`, its `widget` should be of type `MyExtraSpecialWidget`:

```
//MySpecialController:

@interface MySpecialController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) MySpecialWidget *widget;

@end

@implementation MySpecialController

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.widget = [MySpecialWidget new];
    }
}

@end


//MyExtraSpecialController:

@interface MyExtraSpecialController : MySpecialController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyExtraSpecialWidget *widget;

@end

@implementation MyExtraSpecialController

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.widget = [MyExtraSpecialWidget new];
    }
}

@end
```

Now this works in the sense that `MySpecialController` works, and can be used by anyone with the public API. And `MyExtraSpecialController` also works, and follows proper separation of concerns as it assumed nothing about the superclass's behaviour. This is the type of subclass one would create of a framework or library class: robust and unassuming.

What actually happens though is that when I create a new instance of `MyExtraSpecialController`, its superclass first instantiates a `MySpecialWidget`, and then it immediately deallocates that instance and replaces it with an instance of `MyExtraSpecialWidget`. Sure this works, but since I DO have intimate knowledge of the superclass (which basically means that I know exactly what its `init` method does, so I can safely replace it without needing to call it first), I want to avoid this problem and only instantiate a single widget (it just so happens that creating a widget is really expensive and isn't premature optimization). So I want to replace super's implementation entirely so that it doesn't create a widget, and will replace everything else that it does based on my intimate knowledge, but, and this is key, I still want to call `init` further up the chain because I don't know what my replaced class' superclass' `init` method does (`NSObject` in this case), as this is a class I don't have intimate knowledge of.

The immediate solution that comes to mind is to use the Objective-C dynamic runtime to get hold of the grandparent instance, and just call its `init` (which will then take care of calling up the chain if it needs to), therewith bypassing super. But whenever I find myself about to do something like that I always wonder if there is a better approach altogether--conceptually speaking, i.e. to replace rather than augment a superclass' method. Is there?

Comment: Couldn't just check for `[self class]` being a specific subclass and allocate properties based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the instantiation of `self.widget` from the `init` functions and implement a custom "lazy" getter function instead:

```
- (MySpecialWidget *)widget
{
     if (_widget == nil) {
         _wigdet = [MySpecialWidget new];
     }
     return _widget;
}
```

Then you can override this method in the subclass. The widget will be created on the first access to `self.widget`, and either the superclass or the subclass getter is called.

Comment: That's actually a useful pattern I didn't know about (in this context at least), thanks! It doesn't quite answer the question w.r.t replacing vs augmenting superclass behaviour though.

Comment: @lms: Yes, it was meant as alternative approach for your concrete problem. I am sure that more/better answers will follow.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to solve this would be to create a hook for making the widget.

```
@implementation MySpecialController

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.widget = [self makeWidget];
    }
}

- (MySpecialWidget*) makeWidget
 {
     [MySpecialWidget new];
@end
```

Then your subclass can override `makeWidget` to return a `VerySpecialWidget`.  This makes sense when you don't want clients to know about these widgets.

In your scenario, it's possible that clients know *something* about the widgets -- e.g. they want a VerySpecialController in order to get a VerySpecialWidget.  If that's the case, you might want to let the client pick the widget:

```
 [MySpecialController initWith: [MyVerySpecialWidget new]];
```

If the widget is the primary force for making the subclass, either approach may eliminate the need to sprout the subclass in the first place.

The second approach has the additional advantage of making unit testing easier; you can build a MySpecialController and pass it a dummy, stub, or mock without any fuss:

```
 [MySpecialController initWith: [MyTestObjectThatPretendsToBeAWidget new]];
```

But the first pattern is cleaner if the clients shouldn't know anything about widgets.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add an instance method `-widgetClass` to `MySpecialController`

```
@implementation MySpecialController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.widget = [[[self widgetClass] alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)widgetClass
{
    return [MySpecialWidget class];
}

//...

@end
```

and override that method in `MyExtraSpecialController`

```
@implementation MyExtraSpecialController

- (id)widgetClass
{
    return [MyExtraSpecialWidget class];
}

//...

@end
```